# Comparison of a column in Excel based on the result of other column comparison

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

spreadsheet 1 (2 columns)

```
|nmsid_prod | email_id_prod |
|-----------|---------------|
|5454       |abc@gmail.com  |
|5454       |wqr@gmail.com  |
|3444       |edf@gmail.com  |
|3345       |ghj@gmail.com  |
|3444       |ijk@gmail.com  |
```

spreadsheet 2 (2 Columns)

```
|nmsid_contact | email_id_contact|
|--------------|-----------------|
|1234          | xyz@gmail.com   |
|7890          | pqr@gmail.com   |
|5454          | abc@gmail.com   |
|3444          | edf@gmail.com   |
```

if nmsid_prod(sheet1) is same as  nmsid_contact (sheet 2) then it should compare email_id_prod(sheet 1) and email_ld_contact (sheet 2)

Output 1

```
|nmsid_prod | Email_id_comparision |
|-----------|----------------------|
|5454       | Match                |
|3444       | Match                |
```

Output 2

```
|nmsid_prod | Email_id_comparision|
|-----------|---------------------|
|5454       | Mismatch            |
|3444       | Mismatch            |
```

Need excel formula for o/p 1 and o/p2.
Tried with Vlookup and xlookup but not getting desired output...kindly help on the same

Answer (score 0):

For illustrative purposes, the product data is distributed in the range `A1:B6`, while the contact data is distributed in the range `E1:F5` (this is just for illustrative purposes and can be adjusted according to your needs).

To determine if there is a match, enter the following formula in cell `C2` and copy it down accordingly:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($E$1:$E$5=A2)*($F$1:$F$5=B2))>0,"Match","Mismatch")
```

In essence, it is a simple `SUMPRODUCT` function that returns 1 (or a greater value if there are duplicates in the contact data) if there is a match based on ID and email, and 0 otherwise. The result of this function is wrapped in an `IF` function to return the text "Match"/"Mismatch".

The output and data used looks as follows:

[image: Data and Output]